# Closing cmd window after opening it with shellExecute()

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sybase-asa

Good Day.

I have an Powerbuilder application that triggers a batch file to start up a database server.
Below the contents of the batch file:

`"C:\Program Files\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 8\win32\dbsrv8.exe" -c 8m -n DEMO "C:\loadcon\db_demo\demo.db"`

This all works fine. 
However I would like the command window to close automatically after the execution of the batch script. I have spend most of today reading this website and trying options that might work, like adding start, exit, /exit, /c but none work correct. With the start option in front it has a problem with the database switch -c. Repositioning the string quotation marks withing the batch file has undesirable effect on the database startup. However adding /exit at the end - first the the database promts a mssg 'Cant read file /exit' and then the cmd prompt closes - so, something is working but not 100%.

Anybody can enlighten me?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You don't call it with /exit or /c

Batchfile.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 8\win32\dbsrv8.exe" -c 8m -n DEMO "C:\loadcon\db_demo\demo.db"
EXIT
```

It has to be a newline

*edit*

It might be that the program never actually exits, so will never reach the "EXIT" command. Usually when a .bat file is executed with windows scheduler or double-clicked, it will open and close the command prompt as soon as the program finishes and exists.

Might want to consider using vbscript or cscript to execute the command. I can't remember my vbs for batch files so well though :)

*REEDIT 16 Apr*

Re: your comment, try this?

```
cd C:\Program Files\Sybase\SQL Anywhere 8\win32
dbsrv8.exe -c 8m -y -q -n DEMO C:\loadcon\db_demo\demo.db
exit
```

Comment: Nope. Still staying open.
Is there perhaps a windows function that grabs the shellexecute() handle to close it again ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It could be that the program you're running through the batch never exits properly itself which means the "EXIT" command in your .bat file will never fire

Comment: Funny. When I add the EXIT command straight after the last letter on the first line, i.e. ...\demo.db" EXIT, dbsrv8.exe complains that it doesn't understand file 'EXIT'. Anyhow, I will live with it for the time being. Main thing is the batch file executes correctly. The user can close it manually.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an alternative. please try that? nb, it wont work if the dbsrv8.exe never exists itself

Comment: I added a -y to the command line, this forces it to operate without confirmation actions

Comment: also added -q for quiet mode so it doesn't print any messages to screen